# What could be the meaning of typecasting a union's address as an unsigned 8 bit char*?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, header, unions

I came across an embedded c code consisting following user defined types:

```
union framebuffer{
  struct generic_frame frame;
  UCHAR8 data[256];
}

struct generic_frame{
  struct frame_header header;
  UCHAR8 raw[256];
};

struct frame_header{
  uint32_t preamble;
  uint16_t checksum;
  ...
};
int payload = 100;
union framebuffer handshakeReq;
transmit((UCHAR8 *)&handshakeReq,payload);//am not clear on what is (UCHAR8*)&handhshakeReq doing
```

Note: UCHAR8 type is supposed to be treated as unsigned char of 8 bits , values range 0 to 255

Suppose transmit() is sending this data to a socket, what will the other end(a java socket, since java doesn't have unions and structs) will receive ?

Comment: This is serializing your framebuffer as array of `UCHAR8`. But this union is built to exactly avoid this type of things, and I would rewrite it as `transmit(handshakeReq.data, payload)`

Answer (score 0):

The address of a struct or union will be the same address as the first element of the aggregate (well, as far as unions are concerned, they all have the same address.  The reason they are type-casting is because the transmit function expects the payload to be of type `CHAR8 *`.  They could have, instead, used `handshake.data` which is a `CHAR8[256]` which should decay into a pointer.

The reason for these unions in the first-place is because it is a legal form of type-punning in C that allows one to store data as one type and access it as another, which though other means (taking the address of a data-type A and treating it as if it were data-type B such that A and B are incompatible types) would result in undefined behavior.

The reason that the code you are seeing is okay is because there is a special exemption for character-types, such that you are allowed to access any data type as if it were an array of character-types.

Sockets are not aware of such language constructs as `structs` and `unions`.  They just send data as a sequence of byte.  It will be up to the Java code to decode this sequence of bytes when it is received.

Comment: what method at the java end should use to read such data ?

Comment: It will be up to the Java programmer to know what that sequence of bytes means for their program and how to handle it.

Comment: how should the java end get the values of frame_header's preamble, checksum etc ?

Comment: @happinessoverloaded If you have a related question about Java - please ask it in an appropriate form as a separate question. This is out of the scope of this one.